# How can I make voice search know that a certain first name is always that specific contact?

Tags: contacts, google-voice-actions

I have a Nexus 5 with the Okay Google search feature. I can theoretically use it to send text messages hands-free.

However, my wife has a common name, and I have several other contacts with the same first name -- and it wouldn't be surprising for me to know someone with the same last name too. And, she has a work phone number instead of mobile. So, instead of being convenient, there's a whole back-and-forth interrogation.

There must be some way to tell it that when I say "text Karen", I always get *my* Karen. Right? I tried to look for some "remember this decision" setting, or for some way to mark people as special in the People app, but no luck.

I could come up with some silly nickname, I guess, but I don't want to have to do that. I'm hoping there's some real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help? Then you could say "text my wife"...

[Add relationships to your contacts](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4584610?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah, this is as close as we can get, I guess. It still asks me "mobile or work?" every time, which is ridiculous, because her work phone is a landline and does not receive texts.

Comment: @mattdm yes that's ridiculous ,a good idea for a feed back to google ;)